# Grouping and getting the most popular item in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all the items, with the special with the most items first, and they must be grouped by the special.

```
[id] [specials_id] [item]
1         1        bread
2         2        bread
3         2        eggs
4         1        peanut
5         2        macaroni
6         3        peanut
7         2        juice
```

The result should be like:

```
    2 bread
    2 eggs
    2 macaroni
    2 juice
    1 bread
    1 peanut
    3 peanut
```

I tried this, but it only returns one of them:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, item, special_id 
   FROM my_table 
   GROUP BY special_id 
   ORDER BY   `Rows` DESC
```

Can someone please assist me?

Comment: Why do you want your `3 peanut` last? I don't really understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: becouse 3 is the special, and it has the least items in the table

Comment: you seem to just want the last 2 attributes of my_table, but the ordering, I couldnt understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query :

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS Rows1, spl_id, name
FROM `new`
GROUP BY `spl_id` , `name`
ORDER BY   `Rows1` DESC
```